# Uncountable sequence of functions which differ on finitely many values

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I've been struggling with this question I've been assigned for a couple weeks now.

The question is to show from ZFC that there is an uncountable sequence $〈f_α:α→ω:α<ω_1〉$ of functions such that

- Each $f:α→ω$ is injective, and
- for each $α<β<ω_1$, $\{ξ∈α:f_α(ξ)≠f_β(ξ)\}$ is finite.

I believe it will be a matter of constructing the sequence outright, but I can't seem to get the definition right so that it doesn't cause problems at limit ordinals, even if I avoid an infinite number of values in the range of $f_α$.

I may be thinking about this wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know *nothing* about set theory, but reading Asaf Karagila's answers, I've come to suspect that no result using the 'C' in ZFC is ever constructed.

Comment: @pjs36 You probably mean that no construction that relies on choice is 'constructive', which is a fair statement (unless you require some canonical well-order on any given set in your universe, which one may actually do). However, regardless of choice, they are still constructions.